# Coldfusion is not accepting special characters

Tags: templates, cfml

I can not add accents in my cf template it is replaced by ?.
when i put

```
"SubjectPart1": {
     "Type": "String",
     "Default": "Notification : Points correctement transférés",
     "Description": "SubjectPart for ConfirmPointTransferReceiver_F"
```

i received after run my stack

```
"SubjectPart1": {
    "Type": "String",
    "Default": "Notification : Points correctement transf?r?s",
    "Description": "SubjectPart for ConfirmPointTransferReceiver_F"
```

Comment: this is an encoding issue. You might need to set the template encoding in your cfml server settings in accordance of the encoding you're saving the template with your code editor. Try setting everything to UTF-8. What cfml engine are you using and what version?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen on many levels and is due to some part of the stack not being able to map the value of a character to the font glyph.

I would start by making sure that the editor you are using to save your Coldfusion templates is configured to save ColdFusion templates using the UTF-8 encoding. NOTE: Some older editors like Eclipse don't set the byte order mark BOM flag correctly. (This was an issue in the older days)

These days most things use UTF-8 by default but it is worth checking you are using UTF-8 everywhere.

Places I have had issues are:

1. The font I was using could not render the UTF-8 character. (Try a different font)
2. The HTML page had to specify the page encoding as UTF-8
3. The Connector between the application server and CFML had to have UTF-8 enabled.
4. The database table in which we stored data had to have the encoding set to UTF-8
5. The DB driver needed to be set to use UTF-8 encoding.
6. The Lucee/Coldfusion/Railo/Open Blue Dragon server had to be configured to use UTF-8
7. The ColdFusion template needed to be saved in UTF-8 encoding.
8. We need to explicitly move the byte order mark (BOM) flag on Coldfusion Templates back to the beginning of the file because some editors decided to move the BOM into the middle of the file. This one is such an extreme edge case that it would be the very last thing to look at. Modern editors get this right.